# Best way to store and retrieve a list of URLs

Tags: php, mysql

I'm putting together an extremely simple ad server with php and mysql on a website. The site currently has 4 or 5 static pages with lots of dynamic content, so URLs look like this: 
`index.php?pid=1` or `content.php?spec=2`

What I'd like to do is add a field to my table of ads to keep track of that page(s) the ad is going to be displayed on.

Should I store URLs that have an ad as a list of comma separated values?

Once I retrieve this variable, what's the best way to separate the values into an array?

What's the best way to split a string so I can split the page name `$_GET` name and variable (as in 'index, pid, 1' or 'content, spec, 2' using the examples above.) ??

Additional Info:
As an example, doctors.php is structured something like this:

- `doctors.php`  Listing of Doctor Specialties
- `doctors.php?spec=#` Listing of Doctors that have a particular
  specialty
- `doctors.php?pid=#` One specific Doctor's information

I have a few dozen specialties, and a few hundred doctors. I want to be able to place an ad on specific pages/URLs, say `doctors.php?pid=7`

But I also want to be able to place an ad based on, say, all of the doctors who have a specialty with the ID of 6. That could be 60+ pages, so it doesn't really make sense to have separate table rows. If I needed to change the link on the ad, I don't want to have to change it 60 times or search for it.

Comment: Why not just store each URL in its own row?

Answer (score 2):

Don't store as a CSV.

Add separate database rows for each ad / URL combination.

Then retrieving content will be trivial.

Comment: Yup, normalized tables is the way to go.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a lot of redundancy if I had the same ad listed for, say, 60 pages?

Comment: Yes, so you would normalise a step further and have an ad table and a page table. Then link them by having your ad id in the page table or vice versa depending on how you're structuring your data.

Answer (score 0):

Store URls one per line in simple file. Than you can use php function "file" to read this file as an array.

For url split use http://php.net/parse_url function

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think will work...

My ad table will have three variables, (a, b, c)

If I have an ad placed on `doctors.php?spec=12`, I'll store the following:

- `a = 'doctors';`
- `b = 'spec';`
- `c = '12';`

If the ad was meant to display on ALL specialty pages, I'd store:

- `a = 'doctors';`
- `b = 'spec';`
- `c = NULL;`

If something is NULL, it will simply indicate ALL of a set. It seems like an elegant solution, I'll post code if it works.

Answer (score -2):

```
$url = "index.php?pid=1";
$pos = strpos($url, "?");

if ($pos != false) {
  $pieces1 = explode("?", $url);
  $pieces2 = explode("=", $pieces1[1]);
  $array = array($pieces1[0], $pieces2[0], $pieces2[1]);
}else{
  $array = array($url, '', '');
}

print_r($array);
```

You'll need to improve this code if you want it to work for multiple variables in your url for ex: index.php?v=hello&t=world

Also, i did not test this code. I just wrote it without checking the functions etc.

Comment: var_dump(parse_url($url)); Only one line, instead of 8 your lines.